# How to logout if we are using @EnableAuthorizationServer?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I Following this guide:

https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/

I built my own application that use MitreID connect and Google authentication with Oauth2.

I have logout problem with both Google and MitreID but let's focus on the Google side. How can I logout from it?

You can see/download the code from Github:
1) Client

https://github.com/Mazzotta13/ClientApplicationForOauth2AndMitre.git

2) AuthenticationServer

https://github.com/Mazzotta13/MitreIDAndOAuth2.git

Actually I don't have any idea anymore. I tried various things like:
using a logout successUrl in the client that link to the authorization server.
Client:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // @formatter:off
    http.antMatcher("/**").authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/webjars/**","/test").permitAll()
    .anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and()
        .logout()
//          .addLogoutHandler(new MyLogoutHandler())
        .logoutSuccessUrl("http://localhost:8081/exit");
    // @formatter:on
}
```

Controller authentication server:

```
@RequestMapping("/exit")
public void exit(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    // token can be revoked here if needed
    new SecurityContextLogoutHandler().logout(request, null, null);
    try {
        //sending back to client app
        response.sendRedirect(request.getHeader("referer"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The problem could be a xhr token that I don't know how to delete.

edit 1.

In order to remove the token I tried this on the client controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/logout")
  public String logout(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, URISyntaxException {
  SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(null);
  request.logout();  
  SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();

  HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
  if (session != null) {
      session.invalidate();
  }
  CookieClearingLogoutHandler cookieClearingLogoutHandler = new CookieClearingLogoutHandler(AbstractRememberMeServices.SPRING_SECURITY_REMEMBER_ME_COOKIE_KEY);
  SecurityContextLogoutHandler securityContextLogoutHandler = new SecurityContextLogoutHandler();
  cookieClearingLogoutHandler.logout(request, response, null);
  securityContextLogoutHandler.logout(request, response, null);
  SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(null);
  return "You have been logout";
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Delete the access + refresh tokens to logout

Comment: I tried what you can see after "edit 1" in the main post but it didn't work. How can i do this? There is another way?